# How to make @JsonSnakeCase the default for configuration in Dropwizard

Tags: jackson, dropwizard

How will I configure jackson to use snake case in dropwizard instead of putting @JsonSnakeCase in every class ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

And finally am able to find the answer.. Just add below cofiguration.

```
environment.getObjectMapperFactory().setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
```

Comment: `PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` is deprecated. Use `PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Just add this following line in your run() method

```
environment.getObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(
        PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
```

Comment: This - getObjectMapper() - works with more recent versions of dropwizard

Answer (score 0):

```
environment.jersey().register(new JacksonMessageBodyProvider(mapper));
```